# Irrlicht C++ - Creating a proper project with Code::Blocks & MinGW?

Tags: c++, windows, irrlicht

I'm currently learning the Irrlicht library but am having quite a bit of trouble. I use the examples that come with the Irrlicht ZIP archive (which is NOT the examples that come with C::B). Exactly how would I go about solving this "Entry Point not Found" error at runtime? It says something like "gxx_personality_v0" not found or something. What? I don't even know where this is coming from? Does Irrlicht mix good with MinGW?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are building with `gcc` instead of `g++`. The `g++` command links with the C++ library, while `gcc` does not, leading to errors such as yours.

Comment: Now it says "libgcc_s...dll is missing. Please reinstall the application." I guess I link to libgcc?

Comment: Fixed by placing the DLL into the Release folder. Now my only problem is that it starts, but returns 1. No window pops up however. Suggestions?